# check if character vector exists before creating a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame that is dynamically created.  The data frame has 275 columns, and depending on the subset that I create my data frame may or may not have few columns.  For example if the following is my data frame:

```
a  b  c  d
1  1  1  4
2  2  3  3
```

Some time i might get a,b,c and in other instances it could be a,b,d or b,c,d - depending on the availability of the data and over which I do not have control.  Of this, columns b,c,d belong to a group of variables and hence I have to subset them for further data manipulation.  I am using the following code to check if the column exists and create a subset if it did.

```
if("c" %in% colnames(df)) {c <- df[,c("c")]}
```

c is the name of the column in df.

The above code returns a character vector containing values of "c".  The same for b and d as well.  I am converting these character vectors to a data frame using the following code:

```
newdf <- as.data.frame(cbind(b,c,d))
```

This works well if all the columns exits.  However, for example, if b doesn't exist the above code throws a error indicating that b doesn't exist.

How do I create a data frame with only those vectors that exist?  For example, in the above case it will be

```
  c  d
  1  4
  3  3
```

Is there a way I can say, if b doesn't exist create a data frame with c and d or if c doesn't exist create a data frame with b and d?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use intersect

```
df[intersect(v1, names(df))]
#  c d
#1 1 4
#2 3 3
```

Suppose if the `vector` has values that does not exist in the column names of 'df', this works without any error

```
df[intersect(v2, names(df))]
#  c d
#1 1 4
#2 3 3
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("c", "d")
v2 <- c("e", "c", "d")
```